# single query to get all matches based on a field in a previous result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with three fields: name (string) id (number) date (time)

I need a query that will return all matches in a date range and then for each match all other matches with the same id.

ie if:

```
John 100 1/1/2000 
Karen 200 1/1/2000  
Tom 300 2/1/2000
Janet 100 3/1/2000
```

I need a query that for a date range ie 1-1/1/2000 will return both John, Karen and Janet - John and Karen as they are in the date range and Janet as it has the same id (100) of one of the ids (John) from the date result.

Also it is essential for me to know the order of the results as I will need to convert the result into a JSON in the form

```
[ [ dateMatch1, extraIDmatch1, extraIdmatch2 ], [ dateMatch2] ]
```

Or in this case [ ['John', 'Janet' ], ['Karen'] ]

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a few ways you could do this but it depends entirely on what the output would look like... e.g. it could be achieved with a union or a left join, but these would produce different outputs.

Comment: well I will need to turn this into a json in the form { ['John', 'Janet'], ['karen'] } or something of the sort

Comment: Do you need to put 'John' first and 'Janet' second in json because 'John' matches by date and 'Janet' has the same id, or the ordering doesn't matter?

Comment: it matters, basically I need something like [ [ dateMatch1, extraIDmatch1, extraIdmatch2 ], [ dateMatch2] ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id in (select t2.id
               from t t2
               where t2.date between @start and @end
              )
order by id, (case when t.date between @start and @end then 1 else 2 end);
```

Comment: @kofifus . . . The syntax is basically correct if you substitute the right values for the table name, columns, and constant values.

Comment: ok got it, thx !but I think no order is guaranteed here ? I need to be able to get it to order like in the order  { ['John', 'Janet'], ['karen'] } (see updated question)

Comment: Thanks I see you added order by id, but does that guarantee the order of enteries with the same id ? I need the one that matched the date query first ...

Comment: @kofifus . . . Yes, I added the `id`, and another condition for the date.

Comment: I now get an error in the last line: The multi-part identifier "t2.date" could not be bound.

Comment: @kofifus . . . Always use table aliases and qualified columns if you have more than one table reference in a query.